# Flutter cannot call nested json API

Tags: json, flutter, api, flutter-getx

I am still new to flutter development and recently I've been trying to call API. I've managed to do so without placing data into the model and it worked fine. The issue is when I try to serialize the data. I've created a model using app.quicktype.io. and I am not sure how to call it in my views file.

The project is using Getx.

API manager

```
import 'package:api_test_2/models/event.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class ApiManager {
  static var client = http.Client();


  // Future as <List<Event>> maybe ?

  static Future<Event?> fetchEvents() async {
    var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://xposure.ae/wp-json/wp/auditorium/v1/events'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      print(jsonString);
      return eventFromJson(jsonString);
    } else {
      //show error message
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Event model

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final event = eventFromJson(jsonString);

import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Event eventFromJson(String str) => Event.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String eventToJson(Event data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Event {
  Event({
    required this.data,
  });

  List<Datum>? data;

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
    data: json["data"] == null ? null : List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );


  //null check added after data

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": data == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(data!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    required this.eventtitle,
    required this.description,
    required this.eventImage,
    required this.speaker,
    required this.datetime,
    required this.location,
  });

  String? eventtitle;
  String description;
  String? eventImage;
  Speaker? speaker;
  String? datetime;
  Location? location;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    eventtitle: json["Eventtitle"] == null ? null : json["Eventtitle"],
    description: json["Description"] == null ? null : json["Description"],
    eventImage: json["event_image"] == null ? null : json["event_image"],
    speaker: json["Speaker"] == null ? null : Speaker.fromJson(json["Speaker"]),
    datetime: json["datetime"] == null ? null : json["datetime"],
    location: json["Location"] == null ? null : Location.fromJson(json["Location"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Eventtitle": eventtitle == null ? null : eventtitle,
    "Description": description == null ? null : description,
    "event_image": eventImage == null ? null : eventImage,
    "Speaker": speaker == null ? null : speaker!.toJson(),
    "datetime": datetime == null ? null : datetime,
    "Location": location == null ? null : location!.toJson(),
  };
}

class Location {
  Location({
    required this.venue,
    required this.address,
  });

  Venue? venue;
  Address? address;

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location(
    venue: json["venue"] == null ? null : venueValues.map[json["venue"]],
    address: json["address"] == null ? null : addressValues.map[json["address"]],
  );

  //added null checks after reverse

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "venue": venue == null ? null : venueValues.reverse![venue],
    "address": address == null ? null : addressValues.reverse![address],
  };
}

enum Address { SHARJAH_BR_SHARJAH_BR_61110_BR_UNITED_ARAB_EMIRATES }

final addressValues = EnumValues({
  "Sharjah</br>Sharjah,</br>61110,</br>United Arab Emirates": Address.SHARJAH_BR_SHARJAH_BR_61110_BR_UNITED_ARAB_EMIRATES
});

enum Venue { XPOSURE_INTERNATIONAL_PHOTOGRAPHY_FESTIVAL }

final venueValues = EnumValues({
  "Xposure International Photography Festival": Venue.XPOSURE_INTERNATIONAL_PHOTOGRAPHY_FESTIVAL
});

class Speaker {
  Speaker({
    required this.speakername,
    required this.link,
  });

  String speakername;
  String link;

  factory Speaker.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Speaker(
    speakername: json["speakername"] == null ? null : json["speakername"],
    link: json["link"] == null ? null : json["link"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "speakername": speakername == null ? null : speakername,
    "link": link == null ? null : link,
  };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String>? get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

Controller

```
import 'package:api_test_2/models/event.dart';
import 'package:api_test_2/services/api_manager.dart';
import 'package:get/state_manager.dart';


class EventController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  // var eventList = List<Event>().obs;
  var eventList = <Event>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchEvents();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchEvents() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var events = await ApiManager.fetchEvents();
      if (events != null) {

        // added cast as List<Event>
        eventList.value = events as List<Event>;
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Main view

```
import 'package:api_test_2/controllers/event_controller.dart';
import 'package:api_test_2/views/event_tile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/instance_manager.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final EventController eventController = Get.put(EventController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'ShopX',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'avenir',
                        fontSize: 32,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.view_list_rounded), onPressed: () {}),
                IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.grid_view), onPressed: () {}),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Obx(() {
              if (eventController.isLoading.value)
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              else {
                return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                  itemCount: eventController.eventList.length,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return EventTile(eventController.eventList[index]);
                  },
                  staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
                );
              }
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Event tile

```
import 'package:api_test_2/models/event.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';


class EventTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Event event;
  const EventTile(this.event);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 2,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // Text(

            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the conversion to List or Map but I am not sure if it's in my API manager class or the Event model itself. If anyone could help I would be so gratefull.

Comment: Are you fetch data from API and display it into widgets?

Comment: I can fetch data and display it into widgets yes. The problem is when I try to place it into the model class and then call the model into widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual event list is inside the `data` property of your model.
Therefore, your controller should be:

```
class EventController extends GetxController {
  final isLoading = true.obs;
  final event = Rxn<Event>();

 @override
 void onInit() async{
   await fetchEvents();
   super.onInit();
 }

 void fetchEvents() async {
  try {
    isLoading(true);
    var response = await ApiManager.fetchEvents();
    if (response != null) {
    event.value = response;
  }
 } finally {
    isLoading(false);
  }
 }
}
```

And your `StaggeredGridView`:

```
 return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 1,
              itemCount: eventController.event.value.data.length,
              crossAxisSpacing: 16,
              mainAxisSpacing: 16,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return EventTile(eventController.event.value.data[index]);
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
            );
```

And finally, your `EventTile`:

```
class EventTile extends StatelessWidget {
    final Datum datum;
    const EventTile(this.datum);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Card(
      elevation: 2,
      child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
        // Text(

        // ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't figure it out for ages.

Comment: Fixed? If so, please accept this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. Again thank you